# passing looping data through ajax data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My form contains hidden input looping.
in my case, i declare the hidden input in ajax data manually without looping.
so how to loop them in ajax data?

here's my form script

```
<form method="POST" name="myform">
   <?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="data<?php echo $i; ?>" value="data<?php echo $i; ?>">
   <?php } ?>
   <input type='button' name='submitData' value='Submit' onClick='submitData();'>
</form>
```

here's my Ajax script

```
function submitData() {
   var form = document.myform;
   $.ajax({
     url: 'process.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: {
          data1 : form["data1"].value,
          data2 : form["data2"].value,
          data3 : form["data3"].value,
          data4 : form["data4"].value,
          data5 : form["data5"].value
     },
     success: function (result) {
          console.log(result);
     },
     error: function () {
          console.log("error");
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hidden inputs have name and values,

use **[`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)**

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission

```
data : $('form[name=myform]').serialize()
```

This will return `name=value` pairs.

If you need `{name:value}`, use `.each()`

```
var formData = {}
$('form :input:hidden[name^="data"]').each(function(){
    formData[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

And in ajax,

```
data : formData ,
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vo218gcu/2/)**

Comment: I think it should be $('form :input[type="hidden"]')

Comment: @ShaunakD it works, but it will get all of the input hidden, i just want to get the chosen name and value in form, is it possible to do that? thankyou before.

Comment: Updated the code with `$('form :input:hidden[name^="data"]')`

Answer (score 2):

If you're posting the whole form, you can use jQuery's [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) directly in your request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#myform').serialize(),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, a good way to do it is to convert the string to JSON object, and in PHP convert the string in an array:

```
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify({..Your form obj...});

$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: dataJSON,
    success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
    },
    error: function () {
            console.log("error");
    }
});
```

**process.php**

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
print_r($data);
```